# Variable argument support for hook system

Tags: php, web-applications, hook

I am creating a action-hook system for a php application.
Here is what I have done so far.
`$where` is the name of the hook
`$priority` decides the order followed when there are more than one actions for one hook location.
(`hook::execute()` is called when a hook location is reached and my application core runs any hooked actions)

```
class hooks{
    private $hookes;    
    function __construct()
    {
        $hookes=array();        
    }
    function add_action($where,$callback,$priority=50)
    {
        if(!isset($this->hookes[$where]))
            $this->hookes[$where]=array();
        $this->hookes[$where][$callback]=$priority;
    }
    function remove_action($where,$callback)
    {
        if(isset($this->hookes[$where][$callback]))
            unset($this->hookes[$where][$callback]);
    }
    static function compare($a,$b)
    {
        return $a>$b?1:-1;
    }
    function execute($where)
    {
        if(isset($this->hookes[$where])&&is_array($this->hookes[$where]))
        {
            usort($this->hookes[$where],"hook::compare");
            foreach($this->hookes[$where] as $callback=>$priority)
            {
                call_user_func($callback);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**My question is what to do in `execute($where)` to have it accept a variable argument list and pass them in `call_user_func($callback);`** 
For different calls to execute, there may be variable number of parameters to be passed in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function, second argument is array with arguments

Comment: so if I pass `array("data-to-filter",some-other-data,3)` in the call_user_func, it will call the function callback as `function_name("data-to-filter",some-other-data,3);` or `function_name(array("data-to-filter",some-other-data,3));` ??

Comment: function_name("data-to-filter",some-other-data,3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  Change add_action($where,$callback,$priority=50)
```

to

```
  add_action($where,Callable $callback,$priority=50) (PHP 5.4) 
  add_action($where,$callback,$priority=50) ( ALL )
```

CHANGE

```
foreach($this->hookes[$where] as $callback=>$priority)
{
    call_user_func($callback);
}
```

To

```
foreach($this->hookes[$where] as $callback=>$priority)
{

    if(is_callable($callback))
    {
        $callback();
    }
    //call_user_func($callback);
}
```

Sample Code

```
$hooks = new hooks();
$hooks->add_action("WHERE",function()
{
    //Callback Code 
},5);
```

Comment: you are welcome .. This is just more cleaner and easier to read when you begin to have lots of code ... :D